# How to convert android color format?

Tags: android, colors, color-codes

I have a colorpicker dialog, where you can choose colors for a button, textcolor etc. If I log the choosen color, I get a -13459125 number which I dont know what RGB color is. I see that it's a 24-bit color code because 256*256*256 color can be selected, but how can I convert it to a format where I can define its RGB codes? I am not sure why it is negative either...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its packed 4-bytes to an integer as `0xAARRGGBB`

Your value (-13459125), is 0xFF32A14B, or

A=255
R=50
G=161
B=75 in decimal.

If you have a color c, you can get the components with:

```
int red = Color.red(c)
int green = Color.green(c)
```

Etc

Comment: I almost started to add 2^24 to it then put it into an online hexadec-dec converter, but you made my day with this. Thank!